# Where can I get an up-to-date list of destinations by overnight coach from London

Tags: public-transport, transportation, uk, london, buses

I've found a way for people who can sleep on overnight buses/coaches to save time and accommodation by taking night coaches out of London.

I've haphazardly found Plymouth-Penzance, Liverpool-Blackpool and Glasgow-Edinburgh by guessing that they're cities large enough and far away enough to possibly have such service, but is there a quick way to find a list of all UK overnight services by National Express, Megabus, Easybus etc to places tourists are likely to visit?

Comment: What is your definition of night? departing after what time and arriving at the destination after a a minimum time (ie a service departing after 8pm that doesn't arrive before 6AM) Second are you interested in destination only in the UK or are you interested in coaches to Europe?

Comment: Let's say any time between 8 pm and 6 am is fine, but I'm flexible. I was thinking of only UK coaches — anywhere not needing a passport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that searching for <kbd>-2</kbd> on
http://sale.euroticket.pl/start.php?profile=itsoft_redirect_pl_html&cnt=ttable&fid=751937&html=1&offFid=51544
finds night coaches from London, but it's quite hard to read and I don't know how up-to-date it is. Anything better?